# What's the meaning of 預約拘捕(Arrest by Appointment)?

Tags: meaning

- What's the objective of *Appointment*?
- Is it kind of [Wanted poster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanted_poster)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a poster.

> 根據官方香港電台「通識網」解釋，預約拘捕是指執法人員在有證據懷疑一個人違法或有拘捕令的情況下，預先通知及約定對方將會被捕的司法程序。
>
> 實際在執行過程中，警方會事先表明拘捕的理由及涉案人士觸犯的法律，在考慮對方不會潛逃或毀滅證據下，進行有秩序的預約拘捕，可讓對方有足夠的心理 (sic) 準備，減少因突然拘捕而出現衝突。
>
> ---
>
> *According to the description given by liberalstudies.hk, an "Arrest by Appointment" refers to the judicial procedure whereby a law-enforcement officer who, either [through having enough evidence to suspect the conduct of illegal activity] or [having an arrest warrant], gives prior notice to an individual and makes an appointment with them for their arrest.*
>
> *In reality, the police will first give notice of the reason(s) for arrest and the legal case for the offence, and, under an operating assumption that the suspected individual will not attempt to destroy evidence or flee, they will conduct a lawful "Arrest by Appointment" procedure, allowing the suspected individual to prepare themselves for the arrest, minimising the potential shock of an otherwise sudden arrest.*

(NB: This is not legal advice)

Comment: This is helpful description because there is no equivalent law overview (only in my opinion) of "Arrest by Appointment" in Japan. I recognized that at least 2 or 3 administrative bodies (USA, Hong Kong, and UK too?) will adopt the "Arrest by Appointment" rule.

Answer (score 0):

[McClenahen Law](https://www.mattmlaw.com/blog/2013/04/bail-basics-in-pennsylvania/)

> If felony charges arise from an ongoing investigation of which the defendant is aware, then the detective will inform the defendant’s attorney when charges will be filed. The defense attorney, detective and magisterial district court then set up a time for the defendant to turn himself in at the magisterial district court at a set date and time. This is known as a “walk-in arrest” or “arrest by appointment.” Bail will normally be far less in these cases than in those where a defendant is simply arrested by surprise and taken into custody.

[Mary Monson](https://marymonson.co.uk/expect-police-station-basic-guide/)

> Sometimes a police officer will not even explain that coming into the station ‘for a chat’ can mean being interviewed under arrest by appointment.

Arrest by appointment seems big in the UK, maybe that is why it is popular, also, in HK.

[Michael Davis on HK](https://victoriatbhui.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/arrest-by-appointment/)

> Since Monday, Jan. 5, 2015, the police have been calling occupy/umbrella activists to report at police stations at appointment times “to assist in probe.” There are three key issues with this wave of arrests. 1) Activists believe that the arrests are timed to preempt another wave of civil disobedience. The HK government is scheduled to release another consultation report on the electoral arrangements for the Chief Executive in 2017 this afternoon. No one expects the government report to yield to protestors’ demands and activists had promised new actions after this report is released. (Occupy leaders predict fresh protests over new government political reform consultation)
>
> 2. This method of making mass arrests by appointment is a potent counterstrategy against one logic of civil disobedience — mass arrests could normally paralyze the police. Activists are talking about reporting to the police station en masse.
> 3. Core organizers could be subject to years of imprisonment. This could make most leaders of the entire pro-democracy camp — traditional or new, moderate or radical — ineligible for the coming elections.